# After updating from Ubuntu-20 5.8.0-25 to 5.8.0-50 my network drivers stopped working

Tags: drivers, ubuntu-drivers

Hey guys thanks for any help, I'm new to Ubuntu/Linux kernels and I'm enjoying the learning process.

When I boot into 5.8.0-50 or 5.8.0-50-generic, my RTL8111/8168/8411 LAN and Wireless AC 9560 drivers don't work. In both instances

```
lshw
```

returns UNCLAIMED. I have tried a bunch of different things from the internet but without EITHER LAN or WAN, it's basically impossible to do anything. Even trying to grab the old drivers from the UBUNTU boot iso using the Updates & Drivers app, I'm not shown any drivers except those for the 1060.

However, if I boot into 5.8.0-25 or *-generic, everything works fine. (I'm using the 5.8.0-25-generic Boot option right now to post this).

I hope that this isn't too ambiguous of a question, any help would be hugely appreciated. I'm really enjoying learning about Linux and would like to iron out problems like this for future mishaps!
I'm using a laptop,
ASUS ROG-strix,
i7-8750h
1060 6gb

Comment: Ubuntu 20?  There is no such release. Ubuntu uses *yy.mm* format (year.month of release) for all server & desktop releases, the *yy* being used only for IoT and specialist appliance/device releases (also suitable for cloud use) that can use *snap* packages only.  By Ubuntu 20 do you mean Ubuntu Core 20?  as it's a different product to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (desktop or server).